# How to know right power adaptor from monitor label?

Tags: appliances, electricity

A friend gave me his monitor but forgot the power cable.

I want to buy the power wire but I don't know which one is the right adaptor and plug.

Is there a way to know this from the monitor labels (see below)?
[image: Monitor Label]

[image: Monitor Label 2]

[image: Charging port]

[image: Example of some standard power plug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display unfortunately doesn't give you **all** the information you need.

It does tell you the power requirement…

[image]

19V DC at 1.58A
You can use a power supply with a **higher** Amperage capability, but not lower.
The voltage must match exactly.
The input voltage will be, of course, your national mains voltage.

The issue comes in the plug…
Barrel jacks come in many sizes, some of them almost impossible to tell apart by eye. This is where any system with interchangeable multi-plugs comes in. Some of them have reversible polarity too - which is going to come in handy.

The second problem is that there is no indication of polarity.
The socket on the display really should have a polarity marker as well as the DC marker. This says "DC", though they'd already told you that in the info panel, in text & also using the same symbol

[image]

This is missing [source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_symbols)]

[image] or  [image]

to indicate whether centre is positive or negative. So you're going to have to guess. One way will work, the other won't. The socket should have diode protection for if it's connected the wrong way.

So, figure out which plug will fit best first before adding any power [note barrel jacks rarely fit very snugly, so choose the first one in ascending size order that will fit over the centre pin without forcing], then quickly test the polarity both ways to see which works.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin! I wasn't aware of the polarity issue. On the barrel jacks, is there any list of usual barrel jacks per manufacturer? Or even a list of the most usual ones? It seems there is no standard at all!

Comment: There really is no standard. That's why those multi-jack systems are good, if you can't find a 'real' part from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

**Pumping HP into HP display Lifehacks**

The label you show has, "For applicable power supplies see user manual."
BUT…
The ([HP 24f Display User Documents](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/product/hp-value-24-inch-displays/7274745/model/19887867)) are rather opaque about part numbers but shows the following diagram for the power supply 'wire':
[image: HP 24f Display Documents]
It is not a simple wire but an assembly that includes an AC to DC transformer.
You will probably have to contact HP support in your locale with the display model and serial number to get the proper part numbers from their parts list or you may locate what you need with a Web search.
Good Luck!

Comment: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06002131.pdf has a "Power Adaptors" section on page 24.

Comment: Thanks guys! The trickiest part is step 3, connect the transformer to the monitor. Is there any list of usual barrel jacks per manufacturer? @RayButterworth helpful addition! I see the power adaptor section mentions the model number but not the barrel jack.